# You must supply layout_width attribute exception

Tags: android-layout

I have a layout which has title on the top 2 buttons at the bottom and some text views and Edit text in between. I am willing to put these EditText and Text views in scroll view so that I can scroll and EditText does not hide behind keyboard.

Here is my XML file, I am sorry its bit lengthy, but pls, look into this and let me know what is wrong int this. I always get
java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #73: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
I have tried changing width and height lot of ways but i always get this error.

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
        <!-- Title(Preview) Background and  Text-->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/previewBG"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/title_bg">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/previewTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/addDevicesTittle"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            >
            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <!--  Title(Preview) Background and  Text End -->
                <!--  Buttons  -->
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Buttons" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/COL_BTNBG">      

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/btnRefresh_part"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="6dip">


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSave"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="49dip"
                    android:text="@string/btn_manual_save"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:typeface="sans"
                    android:textColor="@color/COL_WHITE"
                    android:layout_weight ="1"
                    android:background="@+drawable/button_02"

                >
                </Button>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="49dip"
                    android:text="@string/btn_manual_cancel"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:typeface="sans"
                    android:textColor="@color/COL_WHITE"
                    android:layout_weight ="1"
                    android:background="@+drawable/button_02"

                >
                </Button>   

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <!--  Buttons End -->

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android.layout_width="50dip"
            android.layout_height="300dip" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/previewBG"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/Data" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:isScrollContainer="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/domain_view"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/txtDomain"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" 
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop = "true" 
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/domain_edit"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:singleLine ="true"
                    android:autoText="false"
                    android:hint ="@string/txtDomainExample"
                    android:capitalize="none"        
                    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:layout_below = "@+id/domain_view"                   
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ip_view"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/manual_IP"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:layout_below = "@+id/domain_edit"                   
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" 
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"                   
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"/>


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/ip_edit"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:singleLine ="true"
                    android:autoText="false"
                    android:hint ="@string/enter_IP_address"
                    android:capitalize="none"        
                    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:layout_below = "@+id/ip_view"                   
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_view"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/txtUserName"
                    android:gravity="left"                  
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:layout_below = "@+id/ip_edit" 
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" 
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dip" 
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/user_edit"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"       
                    android:hint ="@string/txtUserNameExample"
                    android:singleLine ="true"
                    android:autoText="false"
                    android:capitalize="none"
                    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:layout_below = "@+id/user_view"                 
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/password_view"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/txtPassword"
                    android:gravity="left"                  
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:layout_below = "@+id/user_edit" 
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" 
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dip" 
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password_edit"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:hint ="@string/txtPasswordExample"
                    android:singleLine ="true"
                    android:autoText="false"
                    android:capitalize="none"
                    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"                   
                    android:password = "true"
                    android:layout_below = "@+id/password_view"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                 </RelativeLayout>   
        </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your ScrollView has android.layout_width instead of android:layout_width ... similarly layout_height

Observe the dot instead of the colon

That could be your problem

Comment: Thanks!!! Indeed that was the issue... How stupid I feel about myself... and there is no error shown in xml file..

Answer (score 0):

Sachin's answer is a solution for your problem specifically. I just want to add my two cent's worth by saying that, in Eclipse, by switching from the XML view to the Graphical Layout tab, Eclipse tried to parse the XML, found problems with it and suggested quick fixes, which worked like magic. Did not need to start the app in emulator just to see the stacktrace as it exploded.